# MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two `MySQL` tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `item_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_code` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `item_code_UNIQUE` (`item_code` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO item VALUES 
(1, '02', 'item A', '10.00'),
(2, '03', 'item B', '20.00'),
(3, '04', 'item C', '30.00');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price` (
  `price_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`price_id`),
  INDEX `fk_item_price_item1_idx` (`item_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_item_price_item1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`)
    REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

My question is, Just I need to insert data into `price` table from `item` table. In this case, it can not be duplicated the price in `price` table. I tried it like a query as below, but it is inserting duplicate price. Other thing is here I can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `price` (`price`,`item_id`)
  SELECT DISTINCT `i`.`price`, `i`.`item_id`
    FROM `item` `i`
    INNER JOIN `price` `p` ON `p`.`item_id` = `i`.`item_id`;
```

The result of this query is:

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| price_id | price | item_id |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 | 10.00 |       1 |
|        2 | 20.00 |       2 |
|        3 | 30.00 |       3 |
|        4 | 10.00 |       1 |
|        5 | 20.00 |       2 |
|        6 | 30.00 |       3 |
|        7 | 10.00 |       1 |
|        8 | 20.00 |       2 |
|        9 | 30.00 |       3 |
+----------+-------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that each `item`/`price` is unique, you can use a unique index or constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_price_itemid_price ON price(itemid, price);
```

Note that there probably should not be a `price` in the `item` table.  That is suspicious.

If you only want to ensure that your particular update doesn't insert duplicates, then you would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO price (price, item_id)
    SELECT i.price, i.item_id
    FROM item i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM price p
                      WHERE p.item_id = i.item_id AND
                            p.price = i.price
                     );
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed because `item_id` is unique in `item`.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Actually I am looking for a solution without creating a `UNIQUE` index. Can you tell me any other way to do this without `UNIQUE` index?

Comment: Gordon Linoff, your query seems to be working. What does `SELECT 1` mean in your sup query?

Comment: @user3733831 `NOT EXISTS` checks that the row is not found, and does not check the value(s) in the row(s). So you can select anything - 1 (as in the code) or any other literal (for example, 'row found' literal string, current date, and even NULL), some column (for example, p.item_id) or some expression... 1 is simply the most short literal value.